# Visualizing of routing problems over time

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, tikz-datavisualization

I'm more or less a total newbie in Latex and right now I'm in the final days of my masters thesis. I stumbled over a nice way of illustrating a sequence of visitiations in a tour. Think of a tourist who visits certain places within a fixed timespan.
The dashed line symbolizes the path between the nodes taken over time and the full lines representing the opening hours of each node i,j,k and n. 
The connected nodes above the graph represent the tour as a whole. At each node the information about opening hours and visitation duration is given. Between the nodes the traveling time is given.
Maximum number of nodes within the graph is 10.

[image]

Does anyone know about an easy enough solution for me to get this done quick and dirty? Quick and clean would be good too ;)

Comment: Such things are called plots, and `pgfplots` supports symbolic coordinates, which may be handy here. But if you expect others to infer the data from your screen shot you may wait a long time before you get an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not expecting anyone to do that for me. I'm just hoping someone knows an easy solution for this. Maybe there's a package I'm not aware of?

Comment: You find [pgfplots at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need for this is `pgfplots`. Symbolic coordinates can help here. Since `pgfplots` is based on Ti*k*Z, you can add all sorts of Ti*k*Z stuff. Quick: probably yes, dirty: your call, improvable: definitely.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=12cm, height=8cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,b1/.style={circle,minimum
size=1.7em,fill=blue,text=white},b2/.style={circle,minimum
size=1.5em,fill,text=white}]
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=left,
        xmin=8,xmax=26,xlabel=time,xtick={8,10,...,22},
        ylabel=nodes,enlarge y limits=0.1,
         symbolic y coords={n,k,j,i,1},
        ytick=data,
    ]
  \addplot[dashed,no marks] coordinates 
        {(8,1) (9,i) (10,i) (12,j) (15,j) (16,k) (19,k) (20,n)};
  \addplot[mark=triangle*] coordinates  {(8,i) (20,i)};
  \addplot[mark=triangle*] coordinates  {(14,j) (16,j)};
  \addplot[mark=triangle*] coordinates  {(15,k) (22,k)};
  \path (9,1) coordinate (l) (24,1) coordinate (r);
 \end{axis}
  \path (l|-current axis.north) node[b1](1){1} --
  (r|-current axis.north) node[b1](n){n}
  foreach \X in {1,2,3} {coordinate[pos=\X/4,yshift={5pt+iseven(\X)*5pt}] (p\X)};
  \draw[every label/.append style={align=center}] (1) 
   -- node[below]{$t_{1i}=1$} (p1) node[b2,label=above:{blabla\\blabla}](i){i}
   -- node[below]{$t_{ij}=2$} (p2) node[b2,label=above:blabla](j){k}
   -- node[below]{$t_{jk}=1$} (p3) node[b2,label=above:blabla](k){k}
   -- node[below]{$t_{kn}=1$} (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]